# Breakout game java

Tags: java, variables, physics, breakout

I am creating the breakout game and its isn't running just showing the bricks and the paddle and ball. I think its in my for statements in the breakin class.I added in the paddles.getW, paddles. get Y +paddles.getH and for the next for statement I added the balls.getD.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Breakin extends Applet implements Runnable 
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    Thread k;
    int rows=7;
    int columns=8;
    Paddle paddles=new Paddle(50,200,10,40);
    Ball balls=new Ball (40,150,10);
    Brick [] [] bricks =new Brick [rows][columns];
    Graphics dbg;
    Image dbImage;
    Boolean win=false;

    public void init(){
        int xin=0;
        int yin=-15;
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
            yin +=15;
            xin=0;
            for(int c=0; c<columns; c++){
                int game=(int)(Math.random()*4)+1;
                switch(game){
                case 1:bricks[r][c]=new Brick(xin,yin,(Color.yellow),20,10);break;
                case 2:bricks[r][c]=new Brick(xin,yin,(Color.green),20,10);break;
                case 3:bricks[r][c]=new Brick(xin,yin,(Color.orange),20,10);break;
                case 4:bricks[r][c]=new Brick(xin,yin,(Color.red),20,10);break;
                }
                xin+=25;
            }
        }
        balls.setVelocity(2, 2);
                }
    public void start(){
        k=new Thread(this);
        if(k!=null){
            k.start();
        }
            }

    public void run1 ()
    {
        while (true)
        {
        balls.updateVelocity();
        paddles.updateXVelo();

        if (balls.intersects(paddles.getX(),paddles.getY(),paddles.getX() + paddles.getW(),paddles.getY()+ paddles.getH()));
                balls.flipX();

        if(balls.getX()<0 || balls.getX()>(200-balls.getD()))
        balls.flipX();

        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<columns; c++){

                if(bricks[r][c]!=null){
                    if(bricks[r][c].intersects(balls.getX(),balls.getY(),balls.getX()+balls.getD(),balls.getY()+ balls.getD())){
                            bricks[r][c]=null;
                            balls.flipY();}
                }
            }

            }


    repaint();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(20);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex)
    {
    }
        }
    }


    public void destory ()
    {
        k.stop();
    }
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        if(dbImage==null)
        {
            dbImage=createImage(this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            dbg=dbImage.getGraphics();
        }
            dbg.setColor(getBackground());
            dbg.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

            dbg.setColor(getForeground());
            paint(dbg);

            g.drawImage(dbImage,0,0,this);
    }
    public boolean keyDown(Event e, int key)
    {
        if(key==Event.LEFT)
        {
            paddles.setVelocity(0);
            if (paddles.getX()>0)
                paddles.setVelocity(-3);
        }
        if (key==Event.RIGHT)
        {
            paddles.setVelocity(0);
            if (paddles.getX()<200-paddles.getW())//check this out
                paddles.setVelocity(3);
        }
        return true;
    }
    public boolean keyUp(Event e, int Key)
    {
        paddles.setVelocity(0);
        return true; //check
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
            for(int c=0; c<columns; c++){
                if(bricks[r][c]!=null){
                    bricks[r][c].drawBrick(g);
                }
            }
        }
        balls.pinT(g);
        paddles.showT(g);
        }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }
```

Paddle.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Paddle
{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int h;
    private int w;
    private int xVelocity;

    public Paddle (int x, int y, int h, int w){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.w=w;
        this.h=h;
    }
    public void begin(int d, int a){
        if(d==1){
            x+=a;
        }
        if (d<1){
            x-=a;
        }
    }
    public void updateXVelo(){
        x+=xVelocity;
    }
    public void showT(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
        }
    public int getH(){
        return h;
    }
    public int getW(){
        return w;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void setVelocity(int x){
        xVelocity=x;
    }
}
```

Ball.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Ball{
    public int x; 
    public int y;
    public int d;
    public int yvelocity;
    public int xvelocity;

    public Ball (int x, int y, int d)
    {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.d=d;
    }
    public void pinT(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(x,y,d,d);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    }
    public void flipX(){
        xvelocity=-xvelocity;
    }
    public void flipY(){
        yvelocity=-yvelocity;
    }
    public void setX(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y=y;
    }
    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getD(){
        return d;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public void setVelocity(int x, int y){
        xvelocity=x;
        yvelocity=y;
    }
    public void updateVelocity(){
        y+=yvelocity;
        x+=xvelocity;
    }
    public boolean intersects(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2)
    {
        return(x2>=x)&&(x+d>=x1)&&(y2>=y)&&(y+d>=y1);
    }
}
```

Brick.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Brick {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Color color=(Color.red);
    int w;
    int h;
public Brick(int x, int y, Color color, int w, int h){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.color=color;
    this.h=h;
    this.w=w;
}
public boolean intersects(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
{
    return( x2>=x)&&(x+w>=x1)&&(y2>=y)&&(y+h>y1);
}
public void setX(int x){
    this.x=x;
}
public void setY(int y){
    this.y=y;
}
public void setColor (Color color){
    this.color=color;//the :
}
public void drawBrick(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(x,y,w,h);

    }
}
```

Comment: "It isn't working." is not a very elaborate problem description. What have you so that it "stopped" working? Is there an error message? (And btw. we have 2013 a year where 99 of 100 security exploits are addressed to Applet which no one should use anymore...)

Comment: If I was serious about getting help I would ensure that all formatting issues were corrected to allow for easy reading. Speaking of which you should pick a style and stick with it. Alternating bracketing form randomly throughout your file makes it difficult to read.

Comment: Okay sorry about that. What the problem is that there is no errors and  when I run it it just shows the bricks, ball and paddle. It is not showing the movement of the ball and paddle. I think the problem is here.

Comment: if (balls.intersects(paddles.getX(),paddles.getY(),paddles.getX() + paddles.getW(),paddles.getY()+ paddles.getH()));
    balls.flipX();
  
  if(balls.getX()<0 || balls.getX()>(200-balls.getD()))
  balls.flipX();
 
  for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
   for(int c=0; c<columns; c++){
    
    if(bricks[r][c]!=null){
     if(bricks[r][c].intersects(balls.getX(),balls.getY(),balls.getX()+balls.getD(),balls.getY()+ balls.getD())){
       bricks[r][c]=null;
       balls.flipY();}